# Minimize a metric

Tags: optimization, metric-spaces

I have a question about minimizing a metric, i have trouble to find in the back of my head which principle i should apply or how to tackle this problem really.

I have a vector $X$ and a vector $Y$ of lengths $n$, consisting of complex numbers. I now want to find a constant $a$ (i guess also this will be complex?) that minimizes the function $\sum^{n}_{1}|X-aY|^2$  **(e.q 1)**.

The problem this derives from is that i need to minimize $$\sum_{x_1}\sum_{x_2}\sqrt{|E_{reconstructed}\left(x_1,x_2\right)-E_s\left(x_1\right)E_{ref}\left(x_1,x_2\right)|^2}$$ with regards to $E_s\left(x_1\right)$. My approach so far is to solve each position for $E_s\left(x_1\right)$ by solving the problem $$|E_{reconstructed}\left(x_1,(1...n)\right)-E_s\left(x_1\right)E_{ref}\left(x_1,(1...n)\right)|$$, i.e iteratively for each index $x_1$ with the vectors containing all of the values of $x_2$. To clarify, i know $E_{reconstructed}\left(x_1,x_2\right)$ and $E_{ref}\left(x_1,x_2\right)$ and need to solve for the $E_s\left(x_1\right)$ that minimizes (e.q 1) in the case where x and y are replaced with the E-functions given just above here.

Thanks in advance for any help you might offer me.

This is not a hw quesiton.

**EDIT**
Am i on the right track if i'm thinking ... *least squares* ?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are vectors, and you want to minimise $\sum_{k=1}^n |X_k - aY_k|^2$, then this is equivalent to minimising the Euclidean distance from $X_k$ to $aY_k$. Least squares is too advanced to be necessary here; what you're doing is projecting $X$ onto the line $aY$, and the minimising $a$ is $a = \frac{\langle X, Y \rangle}{\|Y\|^2}$

Comment: That actually sounds very reasonable, i'll try it immediately and i'll get back to you shortly

Comment: @TheoBendit Hello, i had to run away yesterday so i'm sorry for my late reply. It seems that that did not do the trick, perhaps i've implemented it wrong or asked my question the wrong way, will look things over and come back to you.

Comment: Ah, I was curious as to whether solved your problem. I wasn't sure that it would; that's why I put it in a comment, instead of an answer.

Comment: Yeah, smart move :) @TheoBendit I am still working with this problem, I have some debugging to do and then i'll get back to you. Could some stupid matlab errors as well ... as me using * instead of .' and that kind of problems ...

Comment: @TheoBendit Is there some sort of chat here, where i could explain the problem in more detail to you and throw some ideas around ?

Comment: There is, but I don't actually know how to instantiate it (it's possibly an option on chat.stackexchange.com). However, I'm about to go to bed, and I'm supposed to be writing my thesis anyway. :-)

Comment: @TheoBendit Okay i'll let you get to your business. Get back to me when you wake up! Gnite. Also working on my thesis here hehe (not in math)